# Create a Java parser for html content similar to mailchimp one

Tags: java, html, parsing

I'd like creare a simple parser in Java that analize a string containing html and replace custom tags and if else/elseif statements, similar to Mailchimp.

Actually I simply replace my custom tags for example: `*|NAME|*`
with the name of the recipient, `*|AGE|*` whith the age of the recipient and so on.

I'd like to add conditional statements to permit expressions like:

```
<html>
<head>....</head>
<body>
*|IF:GENDER=M|*
    Hello Mr.<b>*|NAME|*</b>
*|ELSEIF:GENDER=F|* 
    Hello Mrs.<i>*|NAME|*</i>
*|ELSE:|*
    Dear customer
*|END:IF|*
<p>Bla bla bla</p> 
....
....
</body>
</html>
```

In short, a very similar sintax to [Mailchimp one](http://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/smart/use-conditional-merge-tag-blocks). 
The user can write his own html and add a custom syntax to customize the content based on data.

I think I'm able to create a code that works but I'm searching for the best practice to implement it. I looking for a good way to follow to implements a good code.

Would be nice if the parser can manage nested if/elseif/else statements.

Comment: You are going to invent wheels. I think you should have a look at existing templating engines like velocity or freemarker.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it's very useful! I'll use Freemarker to do this!